# Is there a way to force any function to not be verbose in Python?

Tags: python, pytorch, verbosity

While loading a pretrained model with pytorch via

```
model.load_state_dict(torch.load(MODEL_PATH))
```

the console is flooded with output containing information about the model (which is annoying). Afaik there is no verbosity option, neither in `model.load_state_dict` nor in `torch.load`. Please let me know if I overlooked this parameter.

However, this led me to the question if there is any general way to force a function to be non verbose. Maybe something like:

```
with os.nonverbose():
   model.load_state_dict(torch.load(MODEL_PATH))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't it simply use the standard Python `logging` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @triplee commented, most libraries would use Python logging, which can be modified extensively. I haven't worked with PyTorch before but from https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/330 it looks like it's actaully using `print` (which is horrible if it is but okay).

In general, you can, however, suppress the stdout output of anything by redirecting stdout. Here's a good link https://wrongsideofmemphis.com/2010/03/01/store-standard-output-on-a-variable-in-python/

In your question you ask if this can be done with a context manager. I don't see why not and it seems appropriate given that you want to reset stdout after the function call. Something like this:

```
from io import StringIO  # Python3

import sys

class SilencedStdOut:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_stdout = sys.stdout
        self.result = StringIO()
        sys.stdout = self.result

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):     
 
        sys.stdout = self.old_stdout
        result_string = self.result.getvalue() # use if you want or discard.
```

If you only ever want to supress a single function and never a block of code, however, then a decorator should work fine too.

Comment: This is a brilliant solution, I'd never thought of overwriting stdouts in python.

Comment: From the standard lib, there's also [contextlib.redirect_stdout](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout), which works to the same effect.